# Accidentals and ornaments

Tags: accidentals, baroque-period, ornaments

These are the first two bars of J. S. Bach's Fughetta in c-moll (BWV 961) as edited by Henle.

[image]

Does the second trillo in the second bar start on B flat, so that it cancels the natural on the previous B? I cannot understand the second natural on the next B in that bar otherwise.

More generally, are ornaments supposed to ignore accidentals appearing in the bar and ‘see’ only the signature?

Comment: I've heard the ornament with a Bb on many recordings, and have always played it that way myself. Also, the fact that the B-natural notation is repeated after it is some confirmation of this interpretation? At least by the editors? :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The general rule, given in [Do accidentals earlier in the measure affect a trill?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/35930/70803), is that preceding accidentals *do* affect the ornament.

This case, however, is an exception. It would be very odd, particularly for Bach, to trill between B and Ab, an augmented second. The ornament should be played with Bb. Every [edition on IMSLP](https://imslp.org/wiki/Fughetta_in_C_minor,_BWV_961_(Bach,_Johann_Sebastian)) by a major publisher includes a Bb above the trill sign.

Comment: I upvoted, but consider Henle as to be a major publisher as well. Next step would be a look at an Urtext edition.

Comment: @guidot I wasn’t suggesting Henle isn’t a major publisher. There are independent publications on IMSLP. I believe the Henle is an urtext edition.

Comment: Indeed, the Henle edition is one.

Answer (score 0):

That ornament is a mordent not a trill, there exist an upper mordent and a lower mordent. A brief overview on it's execution can be summised by the following picture. Typically, unless otherwise notated the mordent would follow the key signature.

The notation of the B natural may indicate a passing chord in C minor. There may be the effect of a passing chord or it may simply be a lower auxiliary note. These passing notes often have the lower note raised by a semitone to give the effect of a resolving leading tone.

As with all things Bach the theory is ambiguous on purpose. It is one of the things that makes the textures rich and interesting.

[image: Upper and Lower Mordent.]

Comment: Well, this contradicts none other than Bach's actual description of how to play it and how to call it.